# How to automate text file update in windows 7

Tags: javascript, window

I have a file called environment text file

Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\CPW\CPW.INI

Its has data

PORT : 2012

Now i want to create a exe or some program which will directly run on system and update this particular text file with new data.

PORT : 2014.

I have around 6000 users, so i need to broadcast the program to all of them , so that their file can be updated automated just my running my mailed program.

Please Help 
Ashu

Answer (score 1):

If you use C#, you can use File.WriteAllText to overwrite the text within a file. Encased within a main function you end up with:

```
using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\CPW\CPW.INI", "PORT : 2014");
    }
}
```

Comment: How to make excutable file for this ??

Comment: You would need to use Visual Studio or an online compiler. If you search for "Compile C# Online" I'm sure you can find one.

Comment: using System.IO;
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\CPW\CPW.ENV", 
        "DCE_BROKER=cpwpru1,11558
         DCE_BROKER=cpwpru2,11558");
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\CPW\CPWA\CPW.ENV", 
        "DCE_BROKER=cpwpru1,11558
         DCE_BROKER=cpwpru2,11558");
    }
}

Comment: If content is like DCE_BROKER=cpwpru1,11558
        DCE_BROKER=cpwpru2,11558");

Comment: Yes, that should still work assuming those files exist within those folders. Otherwise an error would be thrown. (It would create new files if they don't exist, but the directory needs to exist)